# CUDA How to access constant memory in device kernel when the constant memory is declared in the host code?

Tags: c, cuda

For the record this is homework so help as little or as much with that in mind. We are using constant memory to store a "mask matrix" that will be used to perform a convolution on a larger matrix. When I am in the host code I am copying the mask to constant memory using the cudaMemcpyToSymbol().

My question is once this is copied over and I launch my device kernel code how does the device know where to access the constant memory mask matrix. Is there a pointer that I need to pass in on kernel launch. Most of the code that the professor gave us is not supposed to be changed (there is no pointer to the mask passed in) but there is always the possibility that he made a mistake ( although it is most likely my understanding of something)

Is the constant memeory declaratoin supposed to be included in the seperate kernel.cu file?

I am minimizing the code to just show the things having to do with the constant memory. As such please don't point out if something is not initialized ect. There is code for that but that is not of concern at this time.

main.cu:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "kernel.cu"

__constant__ float M_d[FILTER_SIZE * FILTER_SIZE];

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

     Matrix M_h, N_h, P_h; // M: filter, N: input image, P: output image

    /* Allocate host memory */
    M_h = allocateMatrix(FILTER_SIZE, FILTER_SIZE);
    N_h = allocateMatrix(imageHeight, imageWidth);
    P_h = allocateMatrix(imageHeight, imageWidth);

    /* Initialize filter and images */
    initMatrix(M_h);
    initMatrix(N_h);


    cudaError_t cudda_ret = cudaMemcpyToSymbol(M_d, M_h.elements, M_h.height * M_h.width * sizeof(float), 0, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    //char* cudda_ret_pointer = cudaGetErrorString(cudda_ret);

    if( cudda_ret != cudaSuccess){
        printf("\n\ncudaMemcpyToSymbol failed\n\n");
        printf("%s, \n\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudda_ret));
    }


    // Launch kernel ----------------------------------------------------------
    printf("Launching kernel..."); fflush(stdout);

    //INSERT CODE HERE
    //block size is 16x16
    //              \\\\\\\\\\\\\**DONE**
    dim_grid = dim3(ceil(N_h.width / (float) BLOCK_SIZE), ceil(N_h.height / (float) BLOCK_SIZE));
    dim_block = dim3(BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE);



    //KERNEL Launch

    convolution<<<dim_grid, dim_block>>>(N_d, P_d);

    return 0;
}
```

kernel.cu:  ***THIS IS WHERE I DO NOT KNOW HOW TO ACCESS THE CONSTANT MEMORY.***

```
//__constant__ float M_c[FILTER_SIZE][FILTER_SIZE];

__global__ void convolution(Matrix N, Matrix P)
{
    /********************************************************************
    Determine input and output indexes of each thread
    Load a tile of the input image to shared memory
    Apply the filter on the input image tile
    Write the compute values to the output image at the correct indexes
    ********************************************************************/

    //INSERT KERNEL CODE HERE

    //__shared__ float N_shared[BLOCK_SIZE][BLOCK_SIZE];


    //int row = (blockIdx.y * blockDim.y) + threadIdx.y;
    //int col = (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x) + threadIdx.x;

}
```

Comment: Why can't you just pass a pointer to the constant memory as an argument to your convolution function?

Answer (score 7):

In "classic" CUDA compilation you *must* define all code and symbols (textures, constant memory, device functions) and any host API calls which access them (including kernel launches, binding to textures, copying to symbols) within the *same translation unit*. This means, effectively, in the same file (or via multiple include statements within the same file). This is because "classic" CUDA compilation doesn't include a device code linker.

Since CUDA 5 was released, there is the possibility of using separate compilation mode and linking different device code objects into a single fatbinary payload on architectures which support it. In that case, you need to declare any __constant__ variables using the extern keyword and *define* the symbol exactly once.

If you can't use separate compilation, then the usual workaround is to define the __constant__ symbol in the same .cu file as your kernel, and include a small host  wrapper function which just calls `cudaMemcpyToSymbol` to set the __constant__ symbol in question. You would probably do the same with kernel calls and texture operations.

Answer (score 4):

Below is a "minimum-sized" example showing the use of `__constant__` symbols. You do not need to pass any pointer to the `__global__` function.

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <stdio.h>

__constant__ float test_const;

__global__ void test_kernel(float* d_test_array) {
    d_test_array[threadIdx.x] = test_const;
}

#include <conio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    float test = 3.f;

    int N = 16;

    float* test_array = (float*)malloc(N*sizeof(float)); 

    float* d_test_array;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_test_array,N*sizeof(float));

    cudaMemcpyToSymbol(test_const, &test, sizeof(float));
    test_kernel<<<1,N>>>(d_test_array);

    cudaMemcpy(test_array,d_test_array,N*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) printf("%i %f\n",i,test_array[i]);

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can do it fine in one file. But when I have a kernel.cu and a main.cu and it is declared in the main I cannot acces it in the kernel.cu. The mask matrix is created in main so how do i refrence it in kernel. When I try it says it is undefined. If I put __constant__ float M_d[FILTER_SIZE * FILTER_SIZE]; in the kernal as well i get the error that it has already been defined.