# CUDA constant memory usage across multiple source files showing different behaviors on cuda-11.2 and cuda-11.4

Tags: cuda

### Minimum repro:

kernel.cu:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

__constant__ int N_GPU;

void wrapper_fn(int *ptr)
{
  cudaMemcpyToSymbol(N_GPU, ptr, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice);
}

__global__ void printKernel() {

    printf("N = %d; \n", N_GPU);

}
```

driver.cu:

```c
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void wrapper_fn(int*);
__global__ void printKernel();

int main()
{
    int N = 10;
    int* d_N_ptr;
    cudaMalloc(&d_N_ptr, sizeof(int));
    cudaMemcpy(d_N_ptr, &N, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDefault);

    wrapper_fn(d_N_ptr);

    printKernel <<<1, 1 >>>();
    cudaPeekAtLastError();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    return 0;
}
```

Both on cuda-11.4 and cuda-11.2, running `nvcc kernel.cu driver.cu` compiles. The expected output (i.e `N = 10;`) is only seen in 11.2 and not 11.4.
Upon running `cuda-gdb` on 11.4, I get the following:

```
...
[New Thread 0x7fffee240700 (LWP 54339)]
warning: Cuda API error detected: cudaMalloc returned (0xde)

warning: Cuda API error detected: cudaMemcpy returned (0xde)

warning: Cuda API error detected: cudaMemcpyToSymbol returned (0xde)

warning: Cuda API error detected: cudaLaunchKernel returned (0xde)

warning: Cuda API error detected: cudaPeekAtLastError returned (0xde)

warning: Cuda API error detected: cudaDeviceSynchronize returned (0xde)

[Thread 0x7fffee240700 (LWP 54339) exited]
...
```

Any particular nvcc flags I'm missing that's important in the 11.4? or particular API changes I'm missing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: EDIT: this question is related to my attempt at trying out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46786475/8274201

Comment: Your use of cudaMemcpyToSymbol is wrong. This code shouldn't work under any circumstances

Comment: I think you meant the missing last param without which it treats it as `cudaMemcpyHostToDevice`. Thanks, have corrected it...

Answer (score 2):

So the answer has to do with my driver version. The error code as seen from the cuda-gdb output (0xde = 222) is due to the fact that the compiled PTX is too new for the driver installed (my driver was 460.35), and the "CUDA Enhanced Compatibility" was used to run on my older driver, that didn't support the necessary PTX JIT.

TLDR; compiling to the exact architecture-specific SASS solved for cuda 11.4.
I did this by adding the the `-arch compute_70` flag to my nvcc compilation command.

Comment: in my case, (I have RTX3060 with 12.2 and driver version 535.xx) -arch sm_86 worked, but -arch compute_86 didn't work